# Counting occurrences of a pattern in a file, include zero for missing patterns

Tags: bash, sorting, count, grep, uniq

I am trying to count occurrences of a pattern (listed in pattern.txt) in a file (file.txt) using:

```
grep -o -w -f pattern.txt file.txt | sort | uniq -c > output.txt
```

This works great, but I would like the output to also include 0 for patterns that do not occur in the file.

How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the patterns to the sort, then substract 1 after the uniq:

```
grep -o -w -F -f pattern.txt file.txt |\
sort - pattern.txt |\
uniq -c |\
awk '{ $1 = sprintf("%7d", $1-1) } 1' > output.txt
```

Note that this only makes sense if the patterns are fixed strings, so I have added the `-F` option to grep.

Also, this particular `awk` script will compact whitespace in the patterns. You'll need more complicated code to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! I didn't know you could append sort with `- pattern.txt` to add it to the end of the list. I also found that `awk '{$1 = $1 - 1; print}'` is a nice clean way to subtract 1 from every count.

Answer (score 0):

Let's face it, what are you doing?

You are looking in a file for some patterns. If they are present, you show them. Afterwards you count the whole thing.

Now you say that for the ones that are not present, you want the number also to be visible.

As a one-liner, I'm afraid this makes no sense.

Therefore I opt for another way of working: `grep` contains a switch (`-v`) for patterns which are NOT present. You can add yourself the number `0` in front of these patterns and append those to your list.

As a starting point: `grep -v -f pattern.txt file.txt` (not tested).

Comment: `-v` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming patterns do not contain white space ...

```
$ cat pattern.txt
abc
def
ghi

$ cat file.txt
line 1 no match
line 2 one abc match
line 3 two ghi matches abc
```

OP's current code:

```
$ grep -o -w -f pattern.txt file.txt | sort | uniq -c
      2 abc
      1 ghi
```

One idea using `join` and OP's current `grep/sort/uniq`:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -a 1 -e 0 -o 2.1,1.1 pattern.txt <(grep -o -w -f pattern.txt file.txt| sort | uniq -c)
```

Where:

- `-1 1 -2 2` - join on file #1 (`-1` == `pattern.txt`) field #1 **and** file #2 (`-2` == `grep/sort/uniq`) field #2
- `-a 1` - include all rows from file #1 even if there is no match
- `-e 0` - fill in empty fields with the character `0`
- `-o 1.1,2.1` - output format: file #2.field #1 `+` file #1.field #1

This generates:

```
2 abc
0 def
1 ghi
```

Personally, I'd probably opt for a more robust solution based on `awk`, but for simple strings (with no white space) this may be sufficient, ymmv ...